# DocuSign JSON SOAP Request

Tags: c++, soap, docusignapi

I am trying to understand how to send SOAP requests with JSON formatted data to docusign. Following this guide is only for pdfs:
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-soap-api/how-to/request-signature/

I created a template on docusign developer and downloaded it, which is in json format.

1. How do I send the data in that format? Is it currently stored as documentBase64, do I need to convert it the data to a PDF, or just set the documents bytes to that value (doc.PDFBytes)? Attempting to do the ladder, gives me a soap error:
   `Soap Fault: The validation of the PDF file failed.`
2. What fields are required to pull out of the json at minimum?
3. Yes, I have the envelope, recipient and tabs set up. I currently am able to send PDFs as is to get signed, just not json formatted data.

Here is an example of attempting to pull out the documentbase64 data and set it to the pdfbytes field:

```
string pdfbytes = json4.value("documentBase64", "oops");
doc->PDFBytes = new xsd__base64Binary();
size_t pdfSize = 0;
// Double conversion to get it to match the datatype for *PDFBytes->ptr*
const unsigned char* t = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>( pdfbytes.c_str() );
unsigned char* y = const_cast<unsigned char*>(t);
doc->PDFBytes->__ptr = y;
doc->PDFBytes->__size = pdfbytes.size();
```

---

UPDATE:
Solved my own problem. You will need to decode your base64 data from docusign. I used the following decoder:
https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/Base64/Encoding-and-decoding-base-64-with-cpp/
Updated code:

```
string pdfbytes = json4.value("documentBase64", "oops");
std::string decoded = base64_decode(pdfbytes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a really good reason, I highly recommend you consider using the [DocuSign eSignature REST API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/) and not the [DocuSign eSignature SOAP API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-soap-api/).

Not every feature is supported by the SOAP API.

You could use https://github.com/jgaa/restc-cpp to make REST API calls from a C++ codebase.

Also, remember that documents sent in the API has to be base64 encoded. This goes for both REST and SOAP.

Comment: To send documents in binary format, use multipart mime API request format. There Is a code example in the DocuSign quick start